# Render Elements are not shown in a shiny tab

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, semantic-ui

I want to add a tabset in my shiny semantic page. Elements that are defined directly in the tab are shown in the app, but render objects do not appear. Here an example:

UI.R:

```
library(shiny)


shinyUI(semanticPage(
  suppressDependencies("bootstrap"),
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  tabset(tabs=
  list(
    list(menu="First Tab", content=
  div(class="ui text shape",
      div(class="sides",
          div(class="ui header side active","This side starts visible."),
          div(class="ui header side","This is yet another side"),
          div(class="ui header side","This is the last side")
      ),
    tags$button(id="test",class="ui button","Flip")
  )),
  list(menu="Second Tab",content=plotOutput("plot1"))
  ))

  ))
```

Server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny.semantic)
library(highlighter)
jsCode <- "
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.shape').shape();
$('#test').on('click', function(){$('.shape').shape('flip up');});
});
"

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  runjs(jsCode)
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot(plot(1,1))

})
```

Here the renderplot "plot1" is not shown in the tab. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I haven't used sematic-ui before, but I tried with your code. I wasn't able to make it render anything (nor text nor plot) inside that second tab. Maybe content can't come from server?? Anyway there are other ways make tabs: https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#sidebar-menu-items-and-tabs or https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/tabPanel.html

Comment: But if I use normal tabPanel, I have to use fluidPage and con not include semantic elements in the app. That was the reason I used semantic package...